# Subir archivo con selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium

Intento subir un archivo con selenium pero no me lo permite.

> La ruta del archivo esta así ya que es la misma ruta donde tengo el .py.

Los test pasan como si fueran exitosos; uso esta página solo para pruebas y aplicarlo a mi proyecto real. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
def test_01_open_app(driver):
    driver.get("https://www.ilovepdf.com/es/comprimir_pdf")

def test_01_open_apps():
    e=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pickfiles']")
    ruta = os.path.abspath("prueba.pdf")
    e.send_keys(ruta)
    time.sleep(4)
```

También intento de la forma básica y igual no carga el archivo:

```
def test_01_open_apps():
    e=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pickfiles']")
    e.send_keys("prueba.pdf")
```

Comment: Estás mandando un objeto `Path` a `send_keys()`. ¿Has probado a transformar antes la ruta a una _string_? De todos modos, no sabemos nada del elemento que se encarga de seleccionar los ficheros. Si no es un campo de entrada de texto, habría que ver su funcionamiento.